# Was Vishnu representative of the sun's rays in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, vishnu

Did Vishnu represent the rays of the sun in the Vedas, and was the story of Trivikrama a metaphor for the sun's rays pervading the three worlds?

Comment: Part - 1 yes. Part 2 - no. Will try to answer in a few days unless someone else answers first

Answer (score 2):

Vishnu in the Rig Veda has no anthropomorphic attributes like hands ,legs, face etc.  His only description is "a youth, vast in size".

Brererton and Jamison RV translation 1 155 6

> 6. With the four times ninety names [=days], he has caused the paired
>    (horses) [=days and nights] to quiver like a wheel set rolling.
>    Having a lofty body, measuring out (the realms?) with verses, the youth
>    who is no boy returns to the challenge.

the 360 days makes it clear that this Vishnu is the Sun.

A Vedic Reader for students by A A MacDonell

> The only anthropomorphic traits mentioned about him are the strides he takes, and the description of him as a youth vast in body who is no longer a child. The central feature of his nature consists in his three steps, connected with which are his exclusive epithets'wide-going' (uru-gaya) and 'wide-striding' ( uru-krama). With these steps he traverses the earth or the terrestrial spaces. Two of his steps are
> visible to men, but the third or highest is beyond the flight of birds or mortal ken. His highest step is like an eye fixed in heaven ; it shines brightly down. It is his dear abode, where pious men and the gods rejoice.

> There can be no doubt that these three steps refer to the course of the sun,
> and in all probability to its passage through the three divisions of the
> world : earth, air, and heaven. Visnu sets in motion like a revolving wheel
> his ninety steeds (= days) with their four names ( = seasons), an allusion to
> the three hundred and sixty days of the solar year. Thus Visnu seems to
> have been originally a personification of the activity of the sun, the swiftly moving luminary that with vast strides passes through the whole universe.

There is another aspect of Vishnu as an offspring of Aditi who is a younger brother of Indra "Upendra" and often assists Indra in his exploits like fighting Vrtra.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, Yes.

**Rig Veda 7.100.6.:**

> किमित्ते विष्णो परिचक्ष्यं भूत्प्र यद्ववक्षे **शिपिविष्टो** अस्मि । मा वर्पो अस्मदप गूह एतद्यदन्यरूपः समिथे बभूथ॥६॥
>
> What was there to be blamed in thee, O Visnu, when thou declaredst, I am **Sipivista**? Hide not this form from us, nor keep it secret, since thou didst wear another shape in battle. 6.

**Note.:** Śipiviṣṭa (शिपिविष्ट) refers to one who is “pervaded by rays” or "the sun rays".

I hope this clarifies your queries.